# Post date/time form submitted with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've looked around for the answer to this but nothing useful came up.

How do you get the time/date of a form submit (SQL & PHP).

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This fetches the current server-time in the format specified that you can then use to store in your database.

You can then store this in your database. Else, you could look at the [TimeStamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) field of a MySQL database.

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

This is a good way to introduce inter-operability between the dateTime in PHP and MySQL. There is a brilliant page [here](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql), which details three ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, `time()` returns the current date in unix timestamp format, it doesn't have to be a user input. Use `time()` whenever you need the time (such as saving to the database).

You may also use `date()` to format it in whatever way you want (to store in a database for instance).

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, just make sure you add the timestamp to the database using the `time()` function.